# creating files (replacing threads into processes)

Tags: python, multithreading, file, process

As in the title, how can I turn threads into `processes` in the program, the program will create files named in the form of the file creation date, but I would like to execute it using `processes`, could anyone give me tips on how to do this correctly?

```
import datetime
import threading


def file():

 try:
  filename = datetime.datetime.now()

  with open(filename.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".txt", "w") as file:
      file.write("")
 except FileExistsError:
  print("file already exists")


threads = []
for i in range(0, 50):
   t = threading.Thread(file())
   threads.append(t)
   t.start()
```